# Controlling how WallpaperManager.setBitmap centers bmp?

Tags: android

I want to set a picture as the wallpaper. I'm simply doing:

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
wm.setBitmap(bmp);
```

The bmp seems to have a really tight zoom level set, such that only like 40% of the photo is actually visibile on the desktop. Slightly exaggerated, but this is how it appears:

```
------------
|          |
|    --    |
|    ||    |  (visible rect of phone in center)
|    --    |
|          |
------------
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to control how the wallpaper manager sets the bmp. Do we implicitly control this by cropping our supplied bmp in a different way?

Thanks